# Get the list of projects which depend on given library

Tags: dependencies

Given that I have an open-source plugin, e.g. [sweetalert2](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2).

How can I get the list of **all open-source projects** (on GitHub) with `sweetalert2` dependency in `package.json`?

[image]

There was similar functionality in https://libraries.io/ but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Go here https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/sweetalert2 or here https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/network/dependents

Comment: Thank you, @curiousdannii! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Could you please make an answer so I can accept it and resolve this question?

Comment: Of course, "the list of all open-source projects (on GitHub) with sweetalert2 dependency in package.json" is just a subset of "the list of projects which depend on given library".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

npm will show you any packages which depend on another package. [Here's what it says for sweetalert2](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/sweetalert2).

But that won't include dev-dependencies, or projects which haven't been published to GitHub. GitHub itself however [also has a list of all public repositories which depend on your package](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/network/dependents).

Comment: As there are many providers like github which let you host the opensource projects, Is there any way to look for dependents on other providers like gitlab etc?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta: SourceForge, BitBucket, [some more](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source_code_hosting_facilities) ... And while OSS sites like Github are very convenient, nothing stops you from just setting up source control, issue tracker, etc. on your own website.

Comment: I'm not able to relate your reply to my question. I asked how can we find users of our OS project.